# How to use Mbrola voices (more than us1, us2 and us3) in Java with FreeTTS?

Tags: java, voice, synthesizer, freetts, mbrola

I want to know if it's possible to use some extra voice from [here](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html) with FreeTTS, rather than only us1, us2 and us3. Particularly a non-english voice.

```
import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;

public class TestTTS {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        VoiceManager freettsVM;
        Voice freettsVoice;
        System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C:\\Java\\mbrola\\mbr301d"); 
        freettsVM = VoiceManager.getInstance();
        freettsVoice = freettsVM.getVoice("mbrola_us1");
        freettsVoice.allocate();
        freettsVoice.speak("Hello");        
    }
}
```

If not, how can that voices be use?

Thanks

Comment: Have you downloaded and copied the voice you downloaded from the MBROLA website into [mbr301d]? You need to also change the voice name. I am unsure of how you downloaded your setup and if the voices were already present in the mbr301d folder which you downloaded. I also do know that the Afrikaans (af1) was faulty when I had tested it, and I suppose more of the voices might be.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I have tested myself and seen that they do not function correctly, am I right to assume you are receiving: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException...